# Bucket SSL / High Bill for Bucket? - Google Cloud

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, billing, bucket, hitcounter

I am hosting a simple static website via Google Bucket right know:
Does the Bill look familiar to you? I am surprised by the high usage numbers.

Does there exist a Hitcounter for GoogleBucket-Websites?

[image: billing information]

How can I secure my bucket website with SSL?
I tried to follow the Loadbalancing Manual, but somehow it doesn`t work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https)

> While you can serve your content through HTTPS using direct URIs such
>   as https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-object, when hosting a
>   static website using a CNAME redirect, Cloud Storage only supports
>   HTTP

As you correctly stated using the [loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers) is a recommended method to serve your content trough HTTPS. If you need help with this I would recommend you to ask another question with the details of the steps followed and the error impeding you to continue.

Using a load balancer will let you use [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#logging) to monitor the access to your account. Using Stackdriver you can get custom metrics and get the number of users entering your website.

Also discussing your Google Cloud Platform billing invoice in Stackoverflow is not recommended as it is not related to programming. If you need help with your billing you should contact the [Billing support team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/) of Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris!

Since I have been very confused with all the bucket-ssl-loadbalancer-stuff,
I have moved to firebase now, which is enough for me.

But I have a new problem now.
I can`t deploy images to my project.
I guess there must be a problem with the format.
I have no problem with some jpg-pictures - the ones i used in the bucket-site
but, new images wont work out.

Do you have any idea, what can be the reason?

Have a nice one!

Comment: In this case would be helpful if you open a new StackOverflow question sharing all the details to reproduce your issue because this issue is not related to the original question